# How to set up 3-levels nested recycler view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have 3-level list and I want to represent this list in 3-levels nest recycler view. 
So, I set up 3 adapters and adapt it to 3 recycler views like this
First level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt_threshold_name"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rv_threshold_list_level_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pd_14"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Second Level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rv_threshold_list_level_2"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Third Level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rv_threshold_list_level_3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pd_14"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I set up each recycler view as normal.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setClipToPadding(false);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

But the level 2 and level 3 recycler view are not showing exactly data. It just show the first item of level 2 recycler view but the background of next item is still there:

[image]

I wonder if i missed some setup of recycler to make it works.
Help me please!

Comment: it will help to debug issue if you will try using fixed heights... can you try using height say 100 for each recycler view

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use nested scroll view and add as many recylerview inside linear layout

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```